# Discord bot python math

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, calculator

I tried to make a simple calculator in my discord bot but it doesnt work,
it gives a error.

btw i use discord.py (discord bot is scripted in python)

Can anyone help me?

this is my code

```
@bot.command()
async def calc(ctx):
   await ctx.send("Number 1: ")

   number_1 = await  bot.wait_for("message" )

   await ctx.send("Operator: ")

   operator = await  bot.wait_for("message" )

   await ctx.send("number 2: ")

   number_2 = await  bot.wait_for("message" )


    number_1 = float(number_1)
    number_2 = float(number_2)

    ouput = none

    if operator == "+":
        ouput = number_1 + number_2

    elif operator == "-":
        output = number_1 - number_2

    elif operator == "/":
        output = number_1 / number_2
    
    elif operator == "*":
        output = number_1 * number_2
    
    else :
        ctx.send(f"invalid input")

    ctx.send(f"Answer: " + str(output))
```

Comment: Hello @WeepyPuppy60, welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll have a better chances of receiving an answer if you include an error you mentioned in your question. You can add it by editing your post.

Comment: Use message.content to fetch for its content. You're using directly message, i.e. number_1.content would give you its content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand some things:

1. `wait_for` function needs `check` to see if the thing that you *wait for* is the thing that you got,
2. `number_1`, `number_2` & `operator` will be message object and not message content so from this object you have to take `content` attribute,
3. In your code variable `output` is sometimes name `ouput` and you assign `none` to it which is completly wrong, it should be `None` with a capital letter,
4. your 2 last `ctx.send()` don't have `await` at the beggining
5. you have to `return` after invalid input or the bot will send the "Answer message" anyway
6. you have some unnecessary `f"strings"` in your code

I think that's it. Here is how your code should look like:

```py
@bot.command()
async def calc(ctx):
    def check(m):
        return len(m.content) >= 1 and m.author != bot.user

    await ctx.send("Number 1: ")
    number_1 = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    await ctx.send("Operator: ")
    operator = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    await ctx.send("number 2: ")
    number_2 = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    try:
        number_1 = float(number_1.content)
        operator = operator.content
        number_2 = float(number_2.content)
    except:
        await ctx.send("invalid input")
        return
    output = None
    if operator == "+":
        output = number_1 + number_2
    elif operator == "-":
        output = number_1 - number_2
    elif operator == "/":
        output = number_1 / number_2
    elif operator == "*":
        output = number_1 * number_2
    else:
        await ctx.send("invalid input")
        return
    await ctx.send("Answer: " + str(output))
```

Also - you made some very begginer-like mistakes there, firstly you should learn the basics of python instead of trying to code a discord bot. I know it is cool and all but it is much more fun when you actually know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a much simpler way to make the calculator

```
import sympy
import numpy
@bot.command()
async def calc(ctx,arg):        #arg is desired calculation(since this code is simple make sure u dont leave any spaces
  answer=N(arg)                  #this will calculate the result    
  ans=np.format_float_positional(answer,trim='-')   #this will remove extra zeros from float
  tu=discord.Embed(title='{0}={1}'.format(arg,ans),color=0XEDAF65)
  await ctx.send(embed=tu)
```

Comment: What is `N` and `np`? Where have you defined that? Please fix the code.